# Asp.Net MVC Form[GET]. Correct action url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I've got search form, which contains checkboxlist which is binded to my model. So when I set GET method to form I got long url:
(I even have exception:

```
The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value.)
```

it's expecting, `[0].IsSelected=false&[0].Id=6&[1].IsSelected=false`...

But I would like url like this

> www.domain.com/Action/Comma-separated-selected-idx

for example:

> www.domain.com/Search/1,6,7

How can I fix,edit form get action? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do a POST instead, then redirect to the URL you desire.

OR

You could capture the form with some JavaScript and build the URL there.

Comment: I do it this way now(Post and redirect). Is it nice practice? I'm interesting with your second advice. As I understand u offer build action at button click with js? What's way is more right?

Comment: Post and redirect is considered best practice - it even has a pattern name: http://devlicio.us/blogs/tim_barcz/archive/2008/08/22/prg-pattern-in-the-asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx

Answer (score 1):

agreed, POST or JS are your best options, I'd opt for a POST.